# how to make onclick function work not only once but each time i click it in pure vanila javascript

Tags: javascript

How to make onclick function work not only once but each time i click it in pure vanila javascript? When I click once the color of body changes, but when i click once more nothing happens...Also im unsure how to set this "change color" in the center. Tried everything just cant make it look right. My css is really bad here but im practicing js. Sorry for being a pure noob...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4hw6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyur7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWwpf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqQEb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMPA1.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of text. It makes it difficult to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable randomNumber is only set once. You need set a new random number each time the function is run.

Also, I recommend using **function** rather than **const** for functions and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your not recalculating a random number every time you click, it's changing the color but back to the same everytime

so move `random_number = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);`
into your `setBackground` function

Comment: Unbelievable how silly I am, that was such a stupid mistake, thx a lot mate!